# Unable to export archive with Here Maps and Swift 2.2, xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, xcode7.3

We are using HERE iOS SDK Premium Edition with Swift in Xcode 7.3 but when we try to exportArchive with the command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -archivePath build/App.xcarchive -exportPath build
```

The exportArchive fails and we run into the error:

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '<path to workspace>/HEREMaps/NMAKit.framework/NMAKit(NMAApplicationContext.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does Here maps support Swift with Xcode 7.3? Is there a project setting we need to set to get it to work?

We are able to run the app in simulator without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcode is a new feature introduces with Xcode 7.

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
>   you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
>   linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize
>   your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version
>   of your app to the store.

Reference [AppThinning Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3)

From the error it seems that the `HERE SDK` is not bitcode enabled and in your project settings bitcode is enabled. For fixing the issue, there are two possible options:

1. Use bitcode enabled version of `Here SDK` (If the vendor provided a bitcode enabled version)
2. Disable the bitcode in your Build Settings

Comment: Correct. HERE SDK (status of today with 3.1.1 available) has no bitcode support, therefor you have to disable it in the build settings.

Comment: Disabling bitcode in the project build settings solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Canna Wen : I too am building an app in Swift using HERE but have never learned Objective-C only Swift. I am struggling A LOT with writing basic stuff and trying to interpret functions and classes shown in the manual from Objective C to Swift. For example the NMARouteManager and other basic stuff. I was wondering if you be so kind and could show me a page or two of your swift code so I can compare and grasp it myself?